# DoubleSided Material not working with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I am using three.js to render a street using ShapeGeometry.

This is the code:

```
import { CONSTANTS, MATERIALS } from '../common'
let ret = new Array<THREE.Mesh>();
    let rampShape = new THREE.Shape();

    rampShape.moveTo(0,0);
    rampShape.lineTo(0, ramp.width);

    //some more line and curve drawing, which works perfectly

    let geo = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(rampShape);
    geo.faces.map( (x) => { x.color.set(MATERIALS.roadMaterial.color); });
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, MATERIALS.roadMaterial);
    mesh.material.side = 2;
    mesh.updateMatrix();
    mesh.rotateX(-Math.PI/2);
    mesh.rotateY(Math.PI);

//this is imported from another file
export const MATERIALS = { 
roadMaterial: new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x333333,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        opacity: 1.0
        })
}
```

But when i rotate the shape, or look at it from "the other side", i just vanishes. I heard that this problem is fixed by using DoubleSided Materials.

I added the side = 2 because i thought maybe the typescript enum somehow messes up the THREE.DoubleSided constant, but it does not work either way.

I installed the Typings with the tsd install command, and they are up-to-date.

Anybody got any idea? If i do not get it to work i guess i could extrude the shape - which i would like to avoid for performance reasons.

Comment: Mesh vanishing could happend due to frustum culling. You could set `mesh.frustumCulled = false` to check if it is an issue.

Comment: I just tried this, unfortunately it did not work.

added  mesh.frustumCulled = false;
to the mesh before rendering, or whould i need to do that before rotating.